# Random Point within a Circle of radius $n$

Tags: inequality

Consider $(X_1,X_2)$ be a random point chosen inside a circle of radius
$n$, with center at the origin and thus $X_1,X_2$ have the joint density 
function
$$p(x_1,x_2) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{n^2\pi}& x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq n^2 \\
                                        0&\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right. .$$

I want to find $P(X_1 \leq X_2),$ But I am having issues trying to figure out
The bounds on $X_2$ and $X_1$ for the double integral. In particular, we know
that $$x_2^2 \leq 1-x_1^2 \implies -\sqrt{1-x_1^2} \leq x_2 \leq \sqrt{1-x_1^2},$$
$x_1$ presents a lower bound if and only if $x_1 > -\sqrt{1-x_1^2}
\leftarrow x_1^2 < 1-x_1^2 \leftarrow x_1^2 < \frac{1}{2}.$ Any suggestions on
a good method to move further with the bounds on this double integration?

Comment: Do you instead mean $P(|X_1| \le |X_2|)$?

Comment: Hard to parse your distribution (just because of the formatting).  Is it asymmetric?  If it is symmetric, then (presumably) $P(X_1=X_2)=0$ and $P(X_1<X_2)=\frac 12$, no?

Comment: Hint: Where on the disc is $X_1\leq X_2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the hemidisc cut below the diagonal $x_1=x_2$.  This involves a double integration over the cartesian intervals: $\{(x_1,x_2)\in [-\sqrt{n^2-x_2^2};x_2]\times[-n/\sqrt 2; n/\sqrt 2]\cup [-\sqrt{n^2-x_2^2};\sqrt{n^2-x_2^2}]\times(n/\sqrt 2;n]\}$

$$\mathsf P(X_1\le X_2) = \int_{-n/\sqrt 2}^{n/\sqrt 2}\int_{-\sqrt{n^2-x_2^2}}^{x_2} p(x_1,x_2)\operatorname d x_1\operatorname d x_2 + \int_{n/\sqrt 2}^n\int_{-\sqrt{n^2-x_2^2}}^{\sqrt{n^2-x_2^2}} p(x_1,x_2)\operatorname d x_1\operatorname d x_2$$

You can try to resolve this integral if you wish.   I assert that the area of this hemidisc is $\tfrac{\pi n^2}{2}$, so the probability is $\tfrac 1 2$ .

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1=P(X_1<X_2)+P(X_2<X_1)+P(X_1=X_2)=2P(X_1<X_2)+P(X_1=X_2)$. But it is easly to proof $P(X_1=X_2)=0$. Then $P(X_1<X_2)=1/2$